# Do Friedmann's equations really result in energy conservation?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion

I was looking into Friedmann's equations for the evolution of the universe and encountered that if one combines them they result in

$$dE + dpV = 0$$

as noted [here](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/%7Evincent/4500.6-001/Cosmology/Friedmann-Equations.htm) in equ. 29.11. and the author claims this is an expression of the first law of thermodynamics and the conservation of energy.

1. But wouldn't this equation say that while a volume of the universe (or the whole universe) is expanding it would lose energy, and this must hold for all volumes of the universe, so the universe as a whole must lose energy?
2. I am not sure if it makes a difference to this case, but also the actual first law of thermodynamics is formulated as
   $$dE + dpV - dQ = 0$$
   so we should actually also include the heat transfer, shouldn't we?
3. In some literature, it is said that the first equation expressed the *local* energy conservation. I am not sure how to understand that, but maybe this resolves my question, does it?
4. Maybe the equation $dE + dpV = 0$ is only an approximation for a special case? I found another formulation, that is maybe more general and looks like this $\dot{\rho}c^2 + 3H(t)(\rho c^2 +p) = 0$. And maybe this formulation is in agreement with the conservation of the total energy of the universe, is it?

Can you resolve my confusion regarding if the conservation of energy is violated by Friedman's equations, if the equ. $dE + dPV = 0$ is complete and valid and regarding the 4 questions I asked? Tnx

Answer (score 1):

> In some literature, it is said that the first equation expressed the local energy conservation. I am not sure how to understand that, but maybe this resolves my question, does it?

Yes, energy-momentum is locally conserved in GR, but not globally conserved. Local conservation doesn't imply global conservation, because energy-momentum is a vector, and we can't define how to add vectors that occur in different places. The vectors inhabit different tangent spaces, and can only be compared by parallel transport, which is path dependent.

> Maybe the equation +=0dE+dpV=0 is only an approximation for a special case?

The web page you linked to states pretty clearly that this is just a "rough interpretation" and that local conservation of energy-momentum is expressed by the zero-divergence property of the stress-energy, their equation 29.12.

Comment: Thanks about the clarification in the first paragraph! Is there an explanation where the energy goes when it gets lost? Regarding your second paragraph - "interpretation" and "approximation" are 2 different things and I asked about the latter. Thanks for the answer, bit I don't like the tone of "states pretty clearly" - if it was clear to me I wouldn't have asked. Nevertheless, I'll give your answer an upvote